# Type comparison / match in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I use `when`  with type cases as mentioned in the code below. It is needed for me in reflection where I check the type of the property/field and set or cast value accordingly. 
In this example,  `Double?` property type is not matching the case `Double::class.java` . If I change the property type to `Double` without `?` then everything works as expected. In this case how do I solve this for nullable properties declared with `?`

```
     valueToSet = when(member?.getter?.returnType?.javaType) {
                Date::class.java -> {                    
                    DateUtil.asDate(LocalDateTime.parse(value))
                }

                Integer::class.java -> value.toInt()               
                Double::class.java -> value.toDouble()

                else ->value.toString();

            }
```

Comment: what is `member`?

Comment: `member` is `KMutableProperty`

Comment: And what is type of `value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`javaType` gives you a `Type` instance, not a Java `Class` instance. Use `classifier` instead and compare against the KClasses. You can get `returnType` directly from the KProperty without going through the getter.

```
valueToSet = when(member?.returnType?.classifier) {
    Date::class -> {
        DateUtil.asDate(LocalDateTime.parse(value))
    }

    Integer::class -> value.toInt()
    Double::class -> value.toDouble()

    else -> value.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Double?` corresponds to `java.lang.Double`, `Double` to `double`. Compare against both types, e.g.:

```
Double::class.java, java.lang.Double::class.java -> value.toDouble()
```

or separate if you want to treat them differently.

(The changes suggested by Tenfour04 are a good idea as well.)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt suggestions. Double?::class.java   was giving `Type in a class literal must not be nullable` error so I tried the solution by Tenfour04 and it worked which solves the problem. Thank you guys  !​

Comment: Strange, I could have sworn it worked for me when tested (answering a different question quite some time ago). Then you could still use `java.lang.Double::class.java`, maybe I misremembered using that?